# How would I put this php curl response in to an array and present it on the web

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I'm trying to figure out how to get the cURL response in to a table by converting it to an array. I guess converting it with the built in json decoder?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.site.com/xyz/xyz',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <omit>",
    "Postman-Token: <omit>",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

?>
```

Comment: Possibly. It would be useful to see what the response is though.... rather than just guessing :)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

given that you add the header `"Accept: application/json"`, i'm going to assume you receive an actual json. to get the json-data into an array, use json_decode. to get a string-representation of an array, there is many things you could use, var_dump, var_export, print_r, and even json_encode, to mention the most popular ones. lets go with print_r. and because print_r's text export of arrays is not (guaranteed to be) compatible with HTML, you'll also need to html-encode the output, that can be done with htmlentities, and you probably want to preserve newlines/formatting here, which HTML does not do by default, you can use `<pre>` html tags to make html preserve the formatting. putting it all together, we get

```
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $data=json_decode($response,true);
  $textual=print_r($data,true);
  $html=htmlentities($textual, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);
  echo '<pre>'.$html.'</pre>';
}
```

- depending on which format you prefer, you can also use json_encode with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, or var_export, or var_dump, to mention a few.

Comment: Hats of Hanshenrik - worked like a Porsche on Autobahn. Badabing badaboom.